# Javascript scoping of readline object

Tags: javascript, scope, readline

Confused why this code hangs after the second prompt:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

function curry () {
  let inputs = []
  function _curry() {
    if (inputs.length > 5) {
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        console.log(inputs[i]);
      }
    } else {
      rl.question("Number?", function(answer) {
        inputs.push(answer)
        rl.close();
        _curry()
      });
    }
  }
  _curry()
}

curry()
```

===>

> ~/Desktop$ node curry.js
>
> > Number?1
> >
> > Number?2
> >
> > HANG

HOWEVER, this:

```
var readline = require('readline');

function curry () {
  let inputs = []
  function _curry() {
    if (inputs.length > 5) {
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        console.log(inputs[i]);
      }
    } else {
      var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
      });
      rl.question("Number?", function(answer) {
        inputs.push(answer)
        rl.close();
        _curry()
      });
    }
  }
  _curry()
}

curry()
```

works fine:

Number?1
Number?2
Number?3
Number?4
Number?5
Number?6
1
2
3
4
5
6

This seems to somehow be a scoping issue? The readline is not closing? Hoisting?

Comment: Why is this function called "curry"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Comment: Well *that* is not what your function is doing.

Comment: agreed... :/ `function curry(length) {
  let inputs = []
  function _curry(input) {
    inputs.push(input)
    if (inputs.length === length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        console.log(inputs[i]);
      }
    } else {
      return _curry
    }
  }
  return _curry
}

curry(4)(1)(2)(3)(4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this has nothing to do with scopes or declaration hoisting. It's just that you're closing the `readline` instance too early (but it appears to be asynchronous so that the second prompt is still shown). You should use

```
function curry () {
  // better don't use a global, especially if you don't leave it open
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  let inputs = []
  function _curry() {
    if (inputs.length > 5) {
      rl.close(); // close it only once you're done with *everything*
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        console.log(inputs[i]);
      }
    } else {
      rl.question("Number?", function(answer) {
        inputs.push(answer)
        _curry()
      });
    }
  }
  _curry()
}
```

Comment: Why does closing the `readline` too early cause it to seemingly not close?

Comment: I would think `rl.close` does not affect the repl output, it just stops reacting to events - it closes the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

It was brought to my attention that my original post is not a strict example of currying, but was intended to produce similar functionality to this, more defensibly curried, example:

```
function curry(length) {
  let inputs = []
  function _curry(input) {
    inputs.push(input)
    if (inputs.length === length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        console.log(inputs[i]);
      }
    } else {
      return _curry
    }
  }
  return _curry
}

curry(4)(1)(2)(3)(4)
```